# Imbalanced text classification by oversampling: correction class probability

Tags: nlp, imbalanced-data

My dataset has 3 class and 900 examples for training. Class distribution is 220, 185, and 500.

I found that if I oversample the training data then I have to correct/calibrate the predicted probability of the test data because after oversampling the training and testing data distribution are not same. This is nicely described [here](https://www.knime.com/blog/correcting-predicted-class-probabilities-in-imbalanced-datasets).

I have three questions:

1. Do I have to do this also for predicting validation dataset (used for early stopping)?
2. Do I have to correct the probabilities for loss calculation?
3. Is this a mandatory step? I am asking this because this might hurt the overall accuracy. Because this will penalize the probabilities of the classes which have less example.

Comment: cross-platform question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/72993/27665

Comment: the post on ds.se was deleted, but it really belongs either there or at stats.se, and the question there was more fleshed-out...

Comment: now at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/73077/55122